# Apache kafka producer and consumer at different servres

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have multiple servers from where the messages will be produced, and I need broker and consumer at one server. If I have both producer and consumer running on same server then it works fine, but not sure what changes need to be done to keep producers separate. I don't want any dependency of zookeeper and kafka servers at producer servers as there are many and they will increase. I tried with changing bootstrap server to the broker/consumer server like 192.168.0.1:9092 while setting up KafkaProducer but still not able to generate messages. Not sure what am I missing, please help me out here.
I have followed https://github.com/mapr-demos/kafka-sample-programs for code.

Tried running both producer and consumer on same server, it works fine.

**Producer.java**

```
public class Producer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // set up the producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
        try (InputStream props = Resources.getResource("producer.props").openStream()) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(props);
            producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
        }

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                // send lots of messages
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
                        "fast-messages",
                        String.format("{\"type\":\"test\", \"t\":%.3f, \"k\":%d}", System.nanoTime() * 1e-9, i)));

                // every so often send to a different topic
                if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
                            "fast-messages",
                            String.format("{\"type\":\"marker\", \"t\":%.3f, \"k\":%d}", System.nanoTime() * 1e-9, i)));
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
                            "summary-markers",
                            String.format("{\"type\":\"other\", \"t\":%.3f, \"k\":%d}", System.nanoTime() * 1e-9, i)));
                    producer.flush();
                    System.out.println("Sent msg number " + i);
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.printf("%s", throwable.getStackTrace());
        } finally {
            producer.close();
        }

    }
```

**prodcuer.props**

```
bootstrap.servers=192.168.0.1:9092
acks=all
retries=0
batch.size=16384
auto.commit.interval.ms=1000
linger.ms=0
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
block.on.buffer.full=true
```

**Consumer.java**

```
public class Consumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // set up house-keeping
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Histogram stats = new Histogram(1, 10000000, 2);
        Histogram global = new Histogram(1, 10000000, 2);

        // and the consumer
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
        try (InputStream props = Resources.getResource("consumer.props").openStream()) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(props);
            if (properties.getProperty("group.id") == null) {
                properties.setProperty("group.id", "group-" + new Random().nextInt(100000));
            }
            consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
        }
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("fast-messages", "summary-markers"));
        int timeouts = 0;
        //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
        while (true) {
            // read records with a short timeout. If we time out, we don't really care.
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(200);
            if (records.count() == 0) {
                timeouts++;
            } else {
                System.out.printf("Got %d records after %d timeouts\n", records.count(), timeouts);
                timeouts = 0;
            }
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                switch (record.topic()) {
                    case "fast-messages":
                        // the send time is encoded inside the message
                        JsonNode msg = mapper.readTree(record.value());
                        switch (msg.get("type").asText()) {
                            case "test":
                                long latency = (long) ((System.nanoTime() * 1e-9 - msg.get("t").asDouble()) * 1000);
                                stats.recordValue(latency);
                                global.recordValue(latency);
                                break;
                            case "marker":
                                // whenever we get a marker message, we should dump out the stats
                                // note that the number of fast messages won't necessarily be quite constant
                                System.out.printf("%d messages received in period, latency(min, max, avg, 99%%) = %d, %d, %.1f, %d (ms)\n",
                                        stats.getTotalCount(),
                                        stats.getValueAtPercentile(0), stats.getValueAtPercentile(100),
                                        stats.getMean(), stats.getValueAtPercentile(99));
                                System.out.printf("%d messages received overall, latency(min, max, avg, 99%%) = %d, %d, %.1f, %d (ms)\n",
                                        global.getTotalCount(),
                                        global.getValueAtPercentile(0), global.getValueAtPercentile(100),
                                        global.getMean(), global.getValueAtPercentile(99));

                                stats.reset();
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal message type: " + msg.get("type"));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "summary-markers":
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Shouldn't be possible to get message on topic " + record.topic());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**consumer.props**

```
bootstrap.servers=192.168.0.1:9092
group.id=test
enable.auto.commit=true
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

# fast session timeout makes it more fun to play with failover
session.timeout.ms=10000

# These buffer sizes seem to be needed to avoid consumer switching to
# a mode where it processes one bufferful every 5 seconds with multiple
# timeouts along the way.  No idea why this happens.
fetch.min.bytes=50000
receive.buffer.bytes=262144
max.partition.fetch.bytes=2097152
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly happens when the producer is not on the broker machine? Do you see any log- or error-messages? You didn't describe your setup but is the IP 192.168.0.1. (broker machine) reachable from the producer machine and is the port 9092 open to the outside (check iptables)?

Another thing: The above code won't give you meaningful results if the producer and consumer are not on the same machine. You use `System.nanoTime()` to measure the latency. But according to the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime):

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin.